# Get all position values from CScrollBar

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Trying to use a `CScrollBar` in my MFC C++ application for Windows7.

I receive all messages just fine and have a handler that looks something like this:

```
void Dialog::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT apos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{    
    SCROLLINFO si;
    si.cbSize = sizeof( si );
    si.fMask = SIF_TRACKPOS;
    m_slider.GetScrollInfo(&si,SIF_TRACKPOS|SIF_POS|SIF_PAGE);
    int nTrackPos = si.nTrackPos; //0 except on TB_THUMBTRACK
    int nPos = si.nPos; //0 except on TB_THUMBTRACK
    UINT nPage = si.nPage; //seems correct always but I dont need it
```

The reason I try to extract the position using `GetScrollInfo` is because they may be bigger than what fits inside a 16bit var, and therefore I cannot use the pos being passed as the argument.

My problem however is that I only get a valid position when dragging the bar and receiving the `TB_THUMBTRACK` as well as the ending `TB_ENDTRACK` for drag operations. If I click in the scrollbar or use the arrows at each end all positions (argument pos, and everything in the `SCROLLINFO` struct except page) will be 0.

Does anyone know how to get the correct positions for all messages? Ie `TB_LINEUP, TB_LINEDOWN` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the sample code for the WM_HSCROLL event handler that's shown in MSDN:

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e14hhbe6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I was totally on the wrong track digging through CScrollBar documentation where I couldn't find anything useful.